# Why can't we use html input tags in javascript directly?

Tags: javascript

Iam a beginner at javascript.Iam trying to write a html input tag in javascipt code that is in .js file.It doesnot showing any output but when Iam writing the input tags in document.write(" "),it was showing the output.Why can't we directly use these html input tags in javascript code?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp Check this out

Comment: Hey srujana, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't take offense, but it seems like you are lacking a basic understanding of the workings of HTML and JavaScript. Maybe you should read up and practice a bit more before asking here. Questions like this will practically answer themselves this way. :)

Comment: Well, that's how the two languages interact. "Why is it the way it is?" is not a type of question suitable for SO. At SO, please ask about "how to do smth?" or, if something doesn't work, "how to fix that?" and may be sometimes about "which way does this work?". For more details, please consult http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

In the analogy of a body, think about HTML as the bones. It is only there to provide structure. JavaScript are the muscles, used to provide functionality and make the website dynamic and CSS is the skin, wrapping everything up in an appealing way.

JavaScript is used to manipulate the DOM structure of a webpage. More on the DOM here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Accessing the DOM allows you to change your HTML dynamically.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off topic. Instead, vote to close them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should always remember that HTML is a markup language, which means it is intended to provide a structural appearance to your content.
Then, JavaScript is for scripting, which means you can have added functionality to your content.

Now, I think you can understand why you were not able to use the HTML tags in JavaScripts.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off topic. Instead, vote to close them.